# Getting number of likes and show comments without access-tokens on Android

Tags: android, facebook, json, facebook-page

I'm trying to make an app that shows a specific page's feed, showing likes and comments too. The thing is though, users do not need to log into Facebook to see it.

If I log out of Facebook and go to a site like .http://www.facebook.com/(PAGE_NAME)", I can see all the posts on that wall, # of likes, and also the comments.

I can find the page ID by going to .http://graph.facebook.com/(PAGE_NAME), and then use that ID, to get a JSON-format by: .https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=(PAGE_ID)&format=json.

By using that URL, I'm able to parse it easily, and get the entire feed:

```
String JSONObjectString = "None";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        JSONObjectString = client.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(JSONObjectString);
```

However, the JSON values for comments and likes are empty:

```
     "comments": "",
     "likes": "",
```

Is it not possible to get #of likes and see comments from a Facebook page without providing some kind of access_token/authentication, and basically just "looking at the feed"?